# Fragment transition crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        sharedImagePreviewFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new DetailTransition());
        sharedImagePreviewFragment.setEnterTransition(new Fade());
        setExitTransition(new Fade());
        sharedImagePreviewFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new DetailTransition());
    }
```

this code before starting a fragment gives a crash. before it was running fine, dues to some changes in the next fragment it started giving me crash, dont know the reason behind it, but commenting this code worked

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference

Error updated to this one, had added wrong error earlier.

Comment: Are you sure this is the line where the app crashes?

Comment: @Xenolion so this is the code which is giving me crash. checked everything in the fragment being started nothing wrong.  even tried with previous code for the same fragment, but getting same error.

surprisingly this was working fine earlier, some changed in the current fragment from where the new fragment is getting started and i started getting crash.
going to previous commit works fine even with this code. but i dont see any dependency for this code on the rest of the code. why crash no idea

Comment: Which line of code is calling `View.getVisibility()`?

Comment: @npace
so i checked this line
` sharedImagePreviewFragment.setEnterTransition(new Fade());`

Comment: You will have to add code of your new changes, probably the modified fragment.

Comment: Resolved - so to initiate the fragment2 method was written in onResume of Fragment1 and This onResume was getting called twice, and so was the initiation of the fragment2. and second time it was called this method got the crash "setEnterTransition(new Fade())"